# name and password not appear into main activity after login

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing

i don't know why after login, into main activity username and password doesn't appear.....i see only `logout` button...why?

I hope that you can help me!

LOGIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputNumeroTelefonico;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputNumeroTelefonico = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numero_telefonico);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String numero_telefonico = inputNumeroTelefonico.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!numero_telefonico.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(numero_telefonico, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String numero_telefonico, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String cognome = user.getString("cognome");

                        String numero_telefonico = user.getString("numero_telefonico");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name,cognome, numero_telefonico, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("numero_telefonico", numero_telefonico);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtNumeroTelefonico;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtNumeroTelefonico = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero_telefonico);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from SQLite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String numero_telefonico = user.get("numero_telefonico");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        System.out.println(name+""+numero_telefonico);

        txtName.setText(name);
        txtNumeroTelefonico.setText(numero_telefonico);

        // Logout button click event
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

LOGIN ACTIVITY.XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/signor_pomidor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numero_telefonico"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_numero_telefonico"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY.XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numero_telefonico"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_logout"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

GET USER DETAIL:
```

if (isset($_POST['numero_telefonico']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

```
    // receiving the post params
    $numero_telefonico = $_POST['numero_telefonico'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($numero_telefonico, $password);

        if ($user != false) {
            // use is found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["cognome"] = $user["cognome"];
            $response["user"]["numero_telefonico"] = $user["numero_telefonico"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }




 public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($numero_telefonico, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE numero_telefonico = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $numero_telefonico);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
            //$hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
                        $hash = $password;

            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7m9y.png)

Comment: Please attach only the **important** code and not all of it. Also, be more descriptive about your errors, what exactly is happening? Try running in debug mode and put breakpoints to see where the data gets lost.

Comment: Can you post your getUserDetails() method

Comment: How are you getting the specific user details??

Comment: @sanoop i edited code added // get the user by email and password

Comment: please mention  your actual requirement

Answer (score 1):

Issue in your MAIN ACTIVITY.XML
Just follow the below codes. I have changed the weight & some of the colors ,but u can change it as per ur requirement. In main Relative Layout i have taken the background as white.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numero_telefonico"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/welcome"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
        android:text="@string/btn_logout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help u.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand...where is my iusse?thanks

Comment: While fetching the data from hashmap is there any name contain ?

Comment: I mean, u have db.getUserDetails() & u r fetching the records & keeping  inside the hash map, & u r fetching the key from hash map as "name". U have to check that the hash map contains any value or not while fetching from your database.

Comment: Then it should work. U just simply check your xml file that all three text views are visible or not.

Comment: i have this error:" android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named numero_telefonico: , while compiling: INSERT INTO user(uid,created_at,numero_telefonico,cognome,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" but i have "numero_telefonico" as column in my local db

Comment: Here we go. So problem is while inserting into ur local db, the values are not inserting into ur table. How many columns do u have ? could u plz show me ur statement while creating user table in ur local db having all the columns?

Comment: i have nine colums...and in one column i have "numero_telefonico"

Comment: Ok, can u give me the insert  & getUserDetails functionality , so that it could easy to identify.

Comment: While inserting records u just check ur column name is same or different ?